# Prepared select statement and getting result

Tags: php

I want to get num rows of this query. Now output is empty and I don't know what to do now...

**EDITED**
And I need to put to "?" text from input..

My code:

```
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->bind_result($email);
            $stmt->fetch();

            echo $email;
            if ($num_rows > 0)
            {
                echo "Exists";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "doesnt exists";
            }

            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
```

Comment: Try to output errors first.

Comment: @JCode how I can output erros?

Comment: `echo $stmt->error;`

Comment: It back nothing

Comment: Try without `$stmt->store_result();`

Comment: I edited my question